# Getting property from pom.xml within java

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven project, and in the pom.xml I set properties as such:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <name>SomeProject</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <some-system-property>1.9.9</some-system-property>
  </properties>
  <...>
</project>
```

I want to pull the some-system-property value from within the java code, similar to

```
String someSystemPropery = System.getProperty("some-system-property");
```

But, this always returns null. Looking over StackOverflow, most of the answers seem to revolve around enhanced maven plugins which modify the code - something that's a nonstarter in my environment.

Is there a way to just get a property value from a pom.xml within the codebase? Alternatively, can one get the version of a dependency as described in the pom.xml (the 1.9.9 value below):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.9</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

from code? Either one would solve my needs

Comment: What is your use-case to get this value dynamically?

Comment: Have you looked at [Parsing a Maven POM](https://javadeveloperslife.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/parsing-a-maven-pom/) from java Developer's Life?

Answer (score 3):

Those are *Maven* properties that apply during the build, not runtime system properties. One typical approach is to use Maven resource filtering to write the value into a properties file in the target directory.

Answer (score 1):

**Maven properties and not system properties.**

Generally you should set the system property for a maven plugin that is triggering the execution:

- `surefire` for unit tests,
- `exec` for execution,
- `jetty` or similar for starting a web container

There is also properties maven plugin than can set properties:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html

Comment: but as you can see [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html), `systemProperties` is deprecated now :)

Comment: So? You will use systemPropertyVariables. They just renamed it.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see your link properly. I thought you're talking about using `systemProperties` instead of `systemPropertyVariables`.

Answer (score 0):

Property values are accessible anywhere within a POM by using the notation ${X}, where X is the property, not outside. All properties accessible via java.lang.System.getProperties() are available as POM properties, such as ${java.home}, but not the other way around. So for your java code, it will need to scan the pom.xml as a xml parsing use case, but not sure why you want to do it.